# How to print prime numbers without using modulus (%)?

Tags: c

How to print prime numbers without using modulus(%)? I tried making an array of the prime numbers and checking whether the remainder was equal to 1. But later I realized that that was not possible:

```
int main()
{
    for (int i = 2; i < num; i++)
    {
        if (num % i == 0) // without using % I am suppposed find prime no
            c++;
    }
    if (c == 0)
        printf("prime");
    else
        printf("not prime");
}
```

Comment: `if ((num / i) * i == num) /* ... */;`

Comment: a tip - `n mod m == (n - (n/m)*m)`

Comment: Try to reformat/re-word the question and read about Eratosthenes.

Comment: Why do the keywords start with an uppercase letter? This is not valid C code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int main()
{
 for(int i=2;i<num;i++)
 {
  if((num-(num/i)*i)==0) // without using %
   c++;
 }
 if(c==0)
  printf("prime");
 else
  printf("not prime");
}
```

This should work.

Comment: Edited post, including indentation which was weird. What about uninitialised num variable?

Answer (score 3):

`a - (n * (a/n))` is equivalent to `a % n`

Comment: +1 for simple correct answer.  Minor note: the C behavior is undefined for both `/0` and `%0`.  I've used a platform that threw a divide by 0 error with `/0`, but with `a%0`, it returned `a`.

Answer (score -1):

```java
// Java Program

class PrimeNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 30;

        for (int j = 2; j < n; j++) {
            if ((num - (num / j) * j) == 0) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        if (count == 0) {
            System.out.println(num + "is Prime");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This appears to be functionally identical to the accepted answer (from six years ago) except with different variable names (and a bug - `j<n`). It may help if you add some text explaining why this is an improvement.